# PageMethod and interaction with UI controls in page asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, pagemethods

we know PageMethod  is static. so i tried to access a label for changing text but could not do just due to PageMethod static in nature. so i wish to show data through gridivew and need the common operation like sorting paging inline update add/delete then how can i accomplish it by pagemethod. i want to use pagemethod because it is faster. so guide me please in detail.tahnks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is not easily accomplished using PageMethods due to the fact that they are static and have no access to the page's control collection. I have used Custom Callback Control  with great success for asynchronously paging and sorting GridView.
Please have a look at this article:
[CallBack Custom Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/CallBackCustomControl.aspx)

Comment: then just tell me what the use of PageMethod?

Comment: Page methods are great if you're willing to spend time developing and maintaining javascript part of client/server interactions. Or you could use them for calling void methods. I have both, PageMethods with defined success callbacks and callback server controls on my web pages. their use is highly situational, but i choose callback control every time i have to rebind a gridview or any other data control on each callback to show updated data, for everything else i use pagemethods.